# Check is element is the last node to wrap a text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to find in DOM the last wrapper of a specific text.

I tried to do it by filter all the elements that have more than zero children like so:

```
allElements.filter(x => x.children.length === 0);
```

But, the problem is that sometimes an element will wrap a text and another element.. for example, I have the following DOM structure:

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <div id="div3">
      <span>Some Text</span>
      This is the text!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In that case my `filter` won't return `div3` because he has children and the text is not in another element.

Also, I cannot check by `innerText` or `textContent` because `div1` and `div2` also holds the text in `div3`.

How can I solve this probelm? **NOTE: I don't want to use `XPath`.**

Comment: Do you have control over the generation of the html? If so, have you tried adding a class to the span wrapper in order to identify it?

Comment: Not so much. Also, the span is not the wanted text.. it's just an example to another child in the text wrapper.